# Finding the domain of an Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to figure out what the domain of [this](https://prnt.sc/lpzapa) function is.

[image]

I was thinking that the domain could be the maximum and minimum amounts of area that is accumulated, but I feel like that's the range of the function rather than the domain. Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the figure we see that the limit of integration is:

$$
0\le 2x-1 \le 6
$$

because the function $f(t)$ is:
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{4-(t-2)^2} \quad for \quad 0\le t \le 4\\
\sqrt{}1-(t-5)^2 \quad for \quad 4\le t \le 6
\end{cases}
$$

from which you can find the domain of the function: $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2}]$.

And , as you say, the range is the interval between the minimum and maximum values of the area:  $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: The minimum value of $h(x)=0$ at $x=1/2$

Comment: Yes, ...My stupid mistake!  Thank you :)